# Python: conserving list structure when working with Composition-Composite classes

Tags: python, list, composition, python-class

How to conserve list structure when working with Composition in Python?

For instance,

```
class Population:
    '''Defines a population of Colonies'''
    def __init__(self, Nc, ...):
        self.number_of_colonies = Nc
        colonies: list[Colony]
        self.colonies = list(Colony(...) for i in range(0, Nc))

class Colony:
    '''Defines a Colony'''
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.propertyA = 1

myPop = Population(10)
```

Therefore `myPop` is a list of 10 colonies, which I access by `myPop.colonies`.
Now, I want a list of `propertyA` across all 10 colonies.
Is there a way to conserve the structure of colony and write `myPop.colonies.propertyA` to return `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]` ?

Basically it'd be nice to have a way around writing `[colony.propertyA for colony in myPop.colonies]` as it appear very frequently in my code.

I'm reading about composition and composites with multiple compositions in Python, but I haven't found the 'A.B.C' structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this out of the box, because `.colonies` part is a `list`. It has access to methods any other `list` has, which means something like `propertyA` isn't really defined.

There are several ways to enable this kind of syntax and I'll present 2 of them, both with some upsides and downsides.

```
class Population:
    '''Defines a population of Colonies'''
    def __init__(self, Nc):
        self.number_of_colonies = Nc
        self.colonies = ColonyList(Colony() for _ in range(0, Nc))

class Colony:
    '''Defines a Colony'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.propertyA = 1

class ColonyList(list[Colony]):
    @property
    def propertyA(self):
        return [el.propertyA for el in self]
    
myPop = Population(10)

print(myPop.colonies.propertyA)
```

This explicitly defines a `propertyA` on the list object, meaning only this specific attribute will be able to be accessed this way. This requires more handling for additional attributes, but is less error-prone, as the property is explicitly created.

Another, slightly similiar (with `list` subclass) approach is to implement `__getattr__` method that will handle all attributes that don't share names with `list` methods, but has a greater chance of attempting to get a value of attribute that does not exist:

```
class ColonyList(list[Colony]):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return [getattr(el, name) for el in self]
```